# elastic stack : i need set Time Filter field name with another field

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

i need read messages(content is logs) from rabbitMq by logstash and then send that to elasticsearch for make visualize monitoring in kibana. so i wrote input for read from rabbitmq in logstash like this:

```
input { 
  rabbitmq {
    queue => "testLogstash"
    host => "localhost"
  }
}
```

and i wrote output configuration for store in elasticsearch in logstash like this:

```
output {
 elasticsearch{
   hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
            index => "d13-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
 }
}
```

Both of them are placed in myConf.conf

In the content of each message,  there is a Json that contains the fields like this:

```
{
  "mDate":"MMMM dd YYYY, HH:mm:ss.SSS"
  "name":"test name"
}
```

But there are two problems. First, there is no date field in the field of creating a new index(Time Filter field name). Second, I use the same timestamp as the default @timestamp, this field will not be displayed in the build type of graphs. I think the reason for this is because of the data type of the field. The field is of type date, but the string is considered.

i try to convert value of field to date by mutate in logstash config like this:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    convert => { "mdate" => "date" }
  }
}
```

---

**Now, two questions arise:
1- Is this the problem? If yes What is the right solution to fix it?
2- My main need is to use the time when messages are entered in the queue, not when Logstash takes them. What is the best solution?**

Comment: In case it helps someone searching, this helped me change my time field for a kibana index: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/9212#issuecomment-553357333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify a value for `@timestamp`, you should get the current system time when elasticsearch indexes the document.  With that, you should be able to see items in kibana.

If I understand you correctly, you'd rather use you `mDate` field for `@timestamp`.  For this, use the [`date{}` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) in logstash.

Comment: tanx, i do it. filter {
    # match date and time
    date {
        "match"  => ["mdate", "MMMM dd YYYY, HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
        "target" => "mdate"
    }
}